# How do I get the suffix (in code) that is being used for urls?

Tags: magento

Magento can add a suffix that is defined by the user to append onto urls. I want to get that suffix from my code. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is is stored in the configuration area?  If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's answer is good but the actual answer to this question is:

```
$suffix = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlSuffix();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's stored in the configuration area, then you access it just as you would any other configuration value, by using `Mage::getStoreConfig($config_path)` where `$config_path` is defined in the `system.xml` of the module that defines it.

If you're not sure of the `$config_path`, then I usually cheat and inspect the textbox/dropdown in the configuration section, take a look at the id, e.g. `dev_log_file`, and translate it to `dev/log/file`.  You'll need to use some intelligence when there are multiple `_` though :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, here is the code ( because I don't understand what you want with URL )

```
<?php
    $currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    $url_parts = split('[/.-]', $currentUrl); // escape characters should change based your url
    echo $url_parts[0]; //check here
?>
```

Comment: Chris seems to suggest that the suffix is stored somewhere in Magento.  Surely it follows that you shouldn't need to do this hackery and just pull it from the config? :S

Answer (score -1):

complete product url:

```
$productId = ***;
$productUrl  = Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore()).Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrlSuffix();
```

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36166228/4174897) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Basically I do this due to page ranking. Today i was once again in search of this solution which in past i had posted on low ranked page and found it after quite some time that's why i post on high rank page as well for ME for next time.

Comment: Well, this is the purpose of duplicate flags.