# Magento Mage::getUrl with suffix

Tags: magento

What is the correct way to handle generating urls in magento when urls have .html suffixes.

For example, to get the following product url:

category/product.html

You cannot simply do `Mage::getUrl('mycategory/myproduct.html')` or `Mage::getUrl('mycategory/myproduct')`

but instead

```
Mage::getUrl() . 'mycategory/myproduct.html'
```

Comment: Looking for this? http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url.html

Comment: No, because the url may be a product but may not be

Comment: Ahh ok, wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You — dont?

The point of having a `getUrl` method is you provide the abstract, behind the scenes `module/controller/action` portions of the URL, and then **the system** handles generating actual HTML urls for you.

Comment: Thats the thing though: magento doesnt add the suffixes.  So it simply doesnt work.  For example I am using a .html suffix for my categories and a call to Mage::getUrl('parentcategory/childcategory') will not add the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get the product url:

```
$productId = ***;
$productUrl  = Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore()).Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrlSuffix();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get a product url, you should use the following

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

If you just have created the product from the backend, you need to get this url just after the  save process, you have to get it by using the event `catalog_product_save_after`, creating an observer class and there you can get the product object thanks to `$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();`

Comment: this method return product url with category path. not clean url
like the followings:
http://yoursite/catalog/product/view/id/256/s/delburne-full-bookcase-storage-bed/category/13/#sthash.KrLGWLMK.dpuf